# Gnuplot - Save result

Tags: c, gnuplot

I create a graph that changes each second using gnuplot.Now, I want to save this graph as gif or png file when my program finishes. How can I do? My C code is below

```
FILE *pipe = popen("gnuplot -persist", "w");

// set axis ranges
fprintf(pipe,"set xrange [0:11]\n");
fprintf(pipe,"set yrange [0:]\n");
int b = 5;int a;
// to make 10 points
std::vector<int> x (10, 0.0); // x values
std::vector<int> y (10, 0.0); // y values
for (a=0;a<5;a++) // 10 plots
{
    x[a] = a;
    y[a] = 2*a;// some function of a
    fprintf(pipe,"plot '-'\n");
    // 1 additional data point per plot
    for (int ii = 0; ii <= a; ii++) {
        fprintf(pipe, "%d %d\n", x[ii], y[ii]); // plot `a` points
    }

    fprintf(pipe,"e\n");    // finally, e
    fflush(pipe);   // flush the pipe to update the plot
    usleep(1000000);// wait a second before updating again
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will not enter in the c (which seems really C++) part --- you just have to send the correct command to `gnuplot`.

Changing the output format is called changing terminal in gnuplot.

For example, to generate a PNG file, in `gnuplot`:

```
[...instruction to make youtr graph...]
set term pngcairo
set output "filename.png"
replot
set output
```

...will generate the graphic in a file called `filename.png`. Remember to switch back to your terminal (or use another instance of `gnuplot`) with something on the style of

```
set term wxt persist
```

before plotting again.

You have a lot of information in `help set term pngcairo`:

> ```
> gnuplot> help set term pngcairo
>  The `pngcairo` terminal device generates output in png. The actual
>  drawing is done via cairo, a 2D graphics library, and pango, a library for
>  laying out and rendering text.
>
>  Syntax:
>          set term pngcairo
>                       {{no}enhanced} {mono|color} {solid|dashed}
>                       {{no}transparent} {{no}crop} {background <rgbcolor>
>                       {font <font>} {fontscale <scale>}
>                       {linewidth <lw>} {rounded|butt} {dashlength <dl>}
>                       {size <XX>{unit},<YY>{unit}}
>
>  This terminal supports an enhanced text mode, which allows font and other
>  formatting commands (subscripts, superscripts, etc.) to be embedded in labels
>  and other text strings. The enhanced text mode syntax is shared with other
>  gnuplot terminal types. See `enhanced` for more details.
> ```

There are terminals for generating bitmap in a lot of formats: just look at

```
help set term jpeg
help set term gif
```

In the `gif` mode you can even generate an animated gif. See:

```
gnuplot> set term gif animate
Terminal type set to 'gif'
Options are 'nocrop font "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf,12" fontscale 1.0 animate delay 10 loop 0 nooptimize size 640,480 '
gnuplot> set output "test.gif"
gnuplot> plot sin(x)
gnuplot> plot sin(x-1)
gnuplot> plot sin(x-2)
gnuplot> plot sin(x-3)
gnuplot> plot sin(x-4)
gnuplot> plot sin(x-5)
gnuplot> set output 
End of animation sequence
```

...and you have in `test.gif`:

[image: Animated gif of sin(x)]

Comment: +1 for gif animate term. I was unaware of this. just a query: is it necessary to `set output` all the time after `plot` or `replot`? I saw `replot` writes in the output file.

Comment: @souravc this depends on the term. If the output is postscript, plotting multiple times without `set output` will create a multi-page file (so for TIFF I think). In animated gif is fundamental *not to* close the output between "frames". Some term simply overwrite the image. The safer way is to issue a void `set output` to close the file after you're done with your image.